# Why I get 'JOIN' instead of 'LEFT JOIN' for 'has_many' relationship in DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, join, dbix-class

I have three table in next relationship:

```
package SafeVPN::DB::Result::Locality;
__PACKAGE__->has_many( servers        => 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Server', 'locality_id', {cascade_delete => 0});
__PACKAGE__->has_many( addresses_view => 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Pool::Address_view', 'locality_id', {cascade_delete => 0});

package SafeVPN::DB::Result::Server;
__PACKAGE__->has_many('addresses_view', 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Pool::Address_view', 'server_id', {cascade_delete => 0});
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to('locality', 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Locality', 'locality_id', {cascade_delete => 0});


package SafeVPN::DB::Result::Pool::Address_view;
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( server   => 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Server',       'server_id'  );
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( locality => 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Locality',     'locality_id');
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( subnet   => 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Pool::Subnet', 'subnet_id'  );
```

in Locality.pm running
this:    `$self->search_related('servers')->search_related('addresses_view')->as_query`
or this:   `$self->servers->search_related('addresses_view')->as_query`

generates next query:

```
SELECT 
  "addresses_view"."id", "addresses_view"."subnet_id", 
  "addresses_view"."ip", "addresses_view"."usage",
  "addresses_view"."notes", "addresses_view"."locality_id", 
  "addresses_view"."server_id" 
FROM "servers" "me"  
JOIN "pool_addresses_view" "addresses_view" 
  ON "addresses_view"."server_id" = "me"."id" 
WHERE ( "me"."locality_id" = ? )
```

But relying on 'has_many' relationship (doc says: **"This relationship refers to zero or more records in the foreign table (e.g. a LEFT JOIN)"**)

I expect 'LEFT JOIN' but, as you see, I get 'JOIN'

So if 'server' from 'locality_id' has no ip addresses I loose that 'server' from results

**UPDATE**
adding attribute **join_type => 'left'** like:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many( addresses_view => 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Pool::Address_view', 'locality_id', {cascade_delete => 0,join_type => 'left'});
__PACKAGE__->has_many('addresses_view', 'SafeVPN::DB::Result::Pool::Address_view', 'server_id', {cascade_delete => 0,join_type => 'left'});
```

has no effect. Maybe BUG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `servers->search_related('addresses_view')` means "*I want addresses of this servers*" not "*this servers with addresses*", so there is no point to do `LEFT JOIN`, it would save servers without addresses in the result, but you don't care about servers anymore (that what `search_related` means).

`search_related` returns the resultset of the new type: `SafeVPN::DB::ResultSet::Pool::Address_view` instead of `SafeVPN::DB::ResultSet::Pool::Server`.

If you want to fetch servers with addresses (i.e. persist the resultset type, but add some extra info), then you might want to use [`prefetch`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#prefetch), not `search_related`.

```
my @servers = $self->servers->search({}, prefetch => 'addresses_view')->all();
foreach my $server (@servers) {
    print $server->addresses_view(); # Doesn't make a SQL query, data is *prefetched*.
}
```

You don't get raw joined relations, all addresses are stored in the `server` result object, that is how ORM works.

Comment: For servers I can $self->addresses_view, but for locality: $self->servers->addresses_view does not work. I done some test and see that: $self->addressed_view and $self->search_related('addresses_view') generates same sql. So I expect for locality: $self->search_related('servers')->search_related('addreses_view') do its job instead of $self->servers->addresses_view

Comment: I've already answered this question in the last paragraph: if you want to fetch servers with addresses (i.e. persist the resultset type, but add some extra info), then you might want to use `prefetch`, not `search_related`.

Comment: I have tryed it: `$self->search( undef, { prefetch => 'servers' } )`  --- Can't locate object method "search" via package "SafeVPN::DB::Result::Locality"

Comment: Know the difference between _result_ and _resultset_. `search` is a _resultset's_ method while you have _result_. On the other hand, `servers` (in your case) is a _result's_ method, not _resultset's_.

Comment: So, `$self->servers` returns the _ResultSet::Server_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77306/discussion-between-vadim-pushtaev-and-eugen-konkov).